# Reason to consider only compact world-sheets in string theory

Tags: string-theory, topology, s-matrix-theory

Generally speaking, the "sum over world-sheets" in string theory involves summing over all possible topologies of compact, orientable and connected, as Polchinski says in page $100$ of his first volume. However, to calculate $S$-matrix elements one consider a scattering amplitude of $n$ strings coming from infinity, interacting in some region and splitting into $m$ strings going to infinity. Each asymptotic string draws a surface whose end can be deformed such that the entire tracjectory of the scattering is a sphere with $n+m$ punctures, which is not compact. So why Polchinski and some other authors work with compact world-sheets?

In Polchinski's volume $1$ this topic is discussed in section 3.5, more specifically in pages $99,100$.

Comment: If nobody answers, I just wanted to let you know that ChatGPT4 knows the answer to your question, and was able to explain the apparent contradiction.

Comment: This is likely just a language issue. Polchinski (and any other string textbook) most definitely consider worldsheets with punctures.

Comment: Can you provide a precise reference with a quote?

Comment: @Rexcirus I've edited the post indicating the precise pages i'm referring to.

Comment: @Daniel This is the kind of question where ChatGPT is very likely to hallucinate. Nor can it be relied upon to give the same answer twice. Can you summarize its explanation? Or maybe paste it in a pastebin and give the link?

Comment: A sphere with $n+m$ punctures is a compact surface. It is closed because it contains all its accumulation points (its boundary of $n+m$ disjoint circles in particular) and bounded because it can be put inside a cube in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n=26$ in the bosonic string case). Then it is compact as follows from the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)

Comment: @RamiroHum-Sah The usual picture we think of in string scattering involes assymptotic strings, i.e. unbounded surfaces.

Comment: @Генивалдо Recall that conformal symmetry is a worldsheet symmetry. Has you've said, the wordlsheet is conformally equivalent to a sphere (with some punctures) just workout the $S$-matrix formalism in this frame for simplicity.